# Web placeholder issue with the input excel data which is getting overlapped

Tags: excel, vba, web, web-scraping, placeholder

While finding if the email address is valid or not, I am getting this issue wherein placeholder from Web site always hides my excel input and it don't go to next command.
Also need to capture the message from innertext of web page in excel next to email address.

Using VBA web will enter email from cell A2 of excel in Sign in page of web and click on next.

```
Sub Test()
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1549662555&rver=6.7.6631.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fsecure%2fPassport.aspx%3frequrl%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fwww.bing.com%252fsearch%253fq%253dmsn%2526form%253dEDGEAR%2526qs%253dPF%2526cvid%253d904d7a00fd1b4125ab81e0f3bb83208e%2526cc%253dUS%2526setlang%253den-US%2526wlsso%253d1%2526wlexpsignin%253d1%26sig%3d22F3BD543C546368216CB1A93D3562E7&lc=1033&id=264960&CSRFToken=f4af0dd6-d72f-4001-9430-e76c6c91253b&aadredir=1"

Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
IE.document.getElementById("i0116").Value = "absdrs@outlook.com"
End Sub
```

If there is an error like "account doesn't exist. Enter a different account" mention "error" in front of cell A2 in excel else "valid". It will keep on going to next value in cell A2 till last. (VBA for web in loop)

Comment: Please limit to one question at a time. There are a number of challenges to overcome for this login.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and code.

Comment: basically i wanted to get some ids checked only and no password.

Comment: if the email id is not correct this web page gives an error, which we need to put in excel next to email address...else if the email id ask for password we need the output as "valid".. This is just making me run for codes and referring other sites....but i think i m in good hands to help..

Comment: im working on IE and just VBA code....

Answer (score 0):

The site is expecting key strokes. Either find a way to trigger this, perhaps with FireEvent, in IE or switch to using selenium basic. After installing [selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0), go VBE > Tools > References and add a reference to Selenium Type Library.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim d As ChromeDriver, loginDetails(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    loginDetails = ws.Range("A1:B2").Value       ' Column A has email, col B has password
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    With d
        .get "https://login.live.com/"

        For i = LBound(loginDetails, 1) To UBound(loginDetails, 1)
            .FindElementById("i0116").SendKeys loginDetails(i, 1)
            .FindElementById("idSIButton9").Click

            'Other code ....
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to add on to help... What we are looking for is error capture...that is innertext i think.. As i m referring some topics...see if helps you....QHarr

Comment: I m still working on this as can't install any other softwares on PC due to restricted mode

Comment: Is that an IT restriction?

Comment: Somewhat yes, but it has access to VBA scripts etc, we have rectricted due to kids and the games they download randomly...

Comment: You could add selenium if IT will let you. Then use the above. It is not something kids will be using.